# GUI app frozen while process and generate a file

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I have a QT GUI application in c++ that aims to process and generates binary files.

The App works fine but it looks like it's frozen when it enters the while loop of processing and writing in the file.
I solve this by coping **`qApp->processEvents();`** into the while loop. but the problem is that it takes much more time for generating a file:

- without `qApp->processEvents();` in the loop => it takes 4second
- with    `qApp->processEvents();` in the loop => it takes 50 second for exact the same file

  ```
   for (unsigned long int k=0; k<DATASIZE ; k++){

   qApp->processEvents();

   /* Some process*/
   DataToFile.push_back(Process_Function(DATA));
  }
  /*Generating file*/
  myFile.write((char *)&DataToFile[0], DataToFile.size()*sizeof (float));
  ```
- DATA SIZE around a couple of millions
- Process_Function: take specific data, calculate the value and return it back.

**Questions:**

1- Is there a way to process the data, generate files without being frozen and without the huge delay of the `qApp->processEvents();`

2- Is it possible to run `qApp->processEvents();` in another thread? / OR is there another way to do it?

Comment: Use a background thread for file generation; keep the event loop thread open for events. You can report back progress information using signals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create an object that encapsulates your work:

```
class Generator : public QObject {
Q_OBJECT
  signals:
  void progress(float);
  void done();
  slots:
  void doWork() {
    QVector<float> DataToFile;
    for (unsigned long int k=0; k<DATASIZE ; k++){
        /* Some process*/
        DataToFile.push_back(Process_Function(DATA));
        if (k % 100 == 0) { // Inform the UI thread every 100 datapoints
            emit progress(k/DATASIZE); 
        }
    }
    myFile.write((char *)&DataToFile[0], DataToFile.size()*sizeof (float));
    emit done();
  }
};
```

Then create a new thread and have the object do its work there:

```
QThread *t = new QThread(this);
Generator *g = new Generator;
g->moveToThread(t);
QObject::connect(t, &QThread::started, g, &Generator::doWork);
QObject::connect(g, &Generator::done, t, &QThread::quit);
QObject::connect(t, &QThread::finished, g, &QObject::deleteLater);
QObject::connect(t, &QThread::finished, t, &QThread::deleteLater);
t->start();
```

The first two `connect` statements tie the lifetime of the generator to that of the thread, the last two clean up everything once the thread exits.

And you can of course connect to the `Generator::progress` signal to monitor the generation progress.

Comment: doWorks function needs different arguments like DATA, counters... can we pass arguments in a slot?

Comment: Either set up the arguments as part of the Generator construction, or use a lambda: `Object::connect(t, &QThread::started, g, [=]() { g->doWork(123, "abc"); });`